# What is the id attribute for the struts <s:form > tag used for?

Tags: html, css, struts2

The struts documentation just says it is the HTML id attribute.  I keep putting it on my pages because it was used on the example pages I based my code on but I don't see that I am using it.  If I don't need it I could make my code cleaner by taking it out but I don't want to break code that works.  I know the HTML id is used with CSS and JavaScript, is that why I need it?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the `id` attribute of [`s:form`](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/form-tag.html) tag is used for generated HTML `form` tag. Read Struts2 doc for the definition of the `id` attribute

> **Name:** id
>   **Required:** false
>   **Default:**
>   **Evaluated:** false
>   **Type:** String
>   **Description:** HTML id attribute

if the form has `id` attribute, keep the value as is, it could be used by JavaScript, CSS, other Struts tags.