# How to fix action using the same id in JSP and JS?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, struts2

I am sending a variable from JSP to java using this code :

```html
 <s:hidden name="checkActes" id="checkActes"></s:hidden>
 
 <s:checkbox id="checkActes" labelposition="left" cssClass=" block-left check" 
 label="%{getText('prestationPsDto.actes')}" key="prestationPsDto.actesSpec"/>
```

After adding the hidden attribute, the action in JS didn't work

```
$('#checkActes').on('click',function() {
            console.log("kjfffkj");
            if($('#checkActes').is(':checked')){
                console.log("kjkj")
                $("#cleCotation").show()
            
            }
            else{
                $("#cleCotation").hide()
                $('#cleCotation').find("input,select").val('');

            }
            
            });
```

I guess the problem is because i am using the same id in both JSP and JS
Is there any solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: Yes: use different IDs

Comment: @MauricePerry how ? I want to use the same checkbox !

Comment: elements may have the same name, not the same ID. Deal with it.

Comment: Both IDs are in the HTML (the DOM). An ID should be in the DOM only once. I don't see any reason for the hidden element to have an ID at all.

Answer (score 1):

The Struts tags `id` attribute are used for HTML ID attribute. Both inputs `hidden` and `select` have the same ID but the JavaScript code finds the first one but should use the second.

The solution to the problem is to use different value for the id attribute.

```html
<s:hidden name="checkActes" id="checkActesID"></s:hidden>
```

You can find detailed information how to use struts tags on the docs site. [There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500266/573032)'s a similar answer on the question which has a link to the docs site

Comment: If my answer helped you then you can check it as accepted the checkbox is on the left of the answer.